# What is the best way to programming android apps in linux?

Tags: android, linux, emulation

I Want to learn android programming, I have a laptop x64 with Linux Mint OS and I've installed Eclipse Indigo and the ADK, but the emulator is very, very, VERY slow. There's an option in windows but it doesn't suppport Linux. I need help from some Linux and Android lover that suggest me some ideas of their tools, some links, books or anything, please. Thank you !.

My Hardware doesn't support hardware acceleration (Pentium x64).

Comment: emulator has always been and probably always will be very slow, use a real device

Comment: The only part of this that is an appropriate question under current policies here is the emulator issue, and that has been covered here extensively already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer has an Intel x86 chip, HAXM is supported on Ubuntu:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

You can also make use of 'Snapshots', on any platform to speedup emulator startup.

If you are really looking for a book suggestion, I did write a book with a few chapters all about the emulator (but really, just search HAXM or Snapshots, and save your money ;-) )- [http://www.amazon.com/Android-Developer-Tools-Essentials-Zipalign/dp/1449328210](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449328210) )

Many people like this 3rd party Android Emulator - http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sure that's all I needed. THANKS !.